# Database with ability to search JSON object

Tags: mongodb, sqlite, database

Please help me find a database solution.

Here is the main requirement: One of the columns (the data column) holds a JSON data object which has to be easily searched.

Database row fields:

- source (string)
- action (string)
- description (string)
- timestamp (epoch timestamp)
- data (can be anything but most likely JSON object or a string)

The nature/schema of this JSON object is unknown (e.g. it can be 1 level deep or 3). The important thing is that tree of the object can be searched.

One possible object:

```
{
  "things": [
    {
      "ip": "123.13.3.3.",
      "sn": "ADF"
    },
    {
      "ip": "123.13.3.3.",
      "sn": "ABC"
    }
  ]
}
```

Another possible object:

```
{
  "ip": "123.13.3.3.",
  "sn": "ABC"
}
```

Example: I want to return all the rows where the data column has a JSON object that has the key/value pair of "SN": "ABC" somewhere in its tree.

Additional Requirements:

- Low overhead and/or simple to set up
- This database will not be getting hundreds/thousands/millions of hits per minute (now or ever)
- Python and/or PHP hooks

Comment: Hi Peter, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you clarify something about your question: what kinds of database system are you considering? For example relational/nosql, free/paid-for, etc.

Comment: Thanks. I think in my case I can go either/or as long as the main requirement is meant. That being said I think relational can work as long as I can store a JSON object in a column and query it. Free that can be used in a commercial application.